# Axios Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:" error in Apollo Server resolver

Tags: https, axios, apollo-server

I have a Reactjs app that connects to a Graphql Apollo Server.
Everything works fine until , i try in the resolver to make a axios request to a different api.
I get the error "Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:""

React app is hosted on a nodejs server using ssl
Apollo server is also using express with ssl certificates
And also the external Api is using ssl

I can't figure out why the request is going out from a unsecure http 
Sample Code is below

```
const httpServer = https.Server({ key, cert }, app);

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
})

apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });
apolloServer.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);

htppServer.listen()



Resolver sample code 
axios.get('https://apiSample.com', {
          httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false })
        })
```

If any one can give me an idea, I would be really grateful

Thank you

PS: if I open https://apiSample.com in the browser it works, if I use Postman it also works if I disable ssl verification

Comment: I think it's because you're using `httpsAgent` without mentioning `httpAgent`? I am truly not sure. I'm facing the same problem, with a similar request to yours.